# UITabIeView CustomCell is not working properly before scrolling... in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I am trying to design a comments Controller but unfortunately i am doing something wrong . I used uiTableview for this purpose.

On run time my customcell with more comment text is hiding behind the customcell with less amount of data.

[image]

This is the layout structure

[image]

As shown above customcell has a uiimageview and a stackview. Stackview has to uilabels. I also setted stackview distribution to proportionally.

Although when i scroll everything becomes fine.

[image]

I also used this in on ViewDidLoad

tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

Comment: Make sure that all constraints are set properly. Also you can try without `UIStackView`

Comment: What is `UICustomCell`?

Comment: Post the code where you fill data in table (`cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath` if any)

Comment: The problem was of constraints. I explored autolayout more and was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a constrains issue still few steps you can do

- Set constrains properly, Number of lines = 0 to label
- Make sure of below code you use in `viewdidload`

> tableView.estimatedRowHeight = YourTableViewHeight
>   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: number of lines are setted to zero and i have added this tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension but its not working.

Comment: try to reload table view using protocol after data fill up in your model

Comment: Also was doing it from the start